# Cannot see output of command prompt anymore (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I have a fairly long-running process running in a windows command prompt.

About an hour ago, the command prompt window stopped "displaying" anything (left window, marked in yellow in screenshot). The process is still running, but I cannot see any of its output. I know the process is still running because it is still writing to a logfile. When I click the command prompt marked in yellow in the screenshot, nothing happens.

[image]

Is there any way to help windows display the output in this command prompt again, without restarting the process?

Comment: Can you try disabling and then enabling the "Peek" function? (It's how you can hold your cursor over an icon and it shows a little preview of the window) You can do this by going to "Performance Options" then in there go to "Visual Effects" uncheck "Enable Peek", apply, then recheck it and apply.

Comment: Thanks jitter. Just tried your suggestion, but had no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Does this happen in PowerShell too or just command prompt?

Comment: So far, only in command prompt

Comment: Can you try right clicking on the little top bar at the top of the window, selecting "Properties" then checking "Use legacy console"? This requires you to relaunch command prompt once for it to activate, but it should solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, I just managed to get it to work again by resetting the buffer size of the command prompt. I guess I'll make that an answer. Thanks for your help nonetheless, jitter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I was able to solve this issue by resetting the buffer size of the command prompt.

Right-click on the command prompt and select properties. In there, change the buffer size (I changed it to 1 in my case).

[image]

Select OK, and it worked in my case. Went back in and changed it back to 50 after.